# Can etale-analytic comparison hold when etale-Cech comparison doesn't?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Assume we have a scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ and a constructible sheaf on $X$. We have a natural morphism from etale cohomology to derived functor cohomology in complex-analytic topology
$$
H_{et}(X, F)\rightarrow H(X(\mathbb{C}), F)
$$
and a natural morphism from etale Cech cohomology to etale cohomology
$$
H_{Cech, et}(X, F)\rightarrow H_{et}(X, F).
$$
Can it so happen that the former is an isomorphism while the latter isn't?

P.S.: one theorem of Artin states that for a scheme of finite type the first morphism is an isomorphism. Another theorem of Artin states that for a quasi-compact scheme such that its every finite subset is contained in an affine open the second morphism is an isomorphism. There probably should be some examples for "weird" schemes of finite type but I can not think of one.

Comment: I do not understand why this explanation has anything to do with Cech cohomology... The hypercovering theorem computes actual cohomology, not Cech cohomology.